# Linear Mapping Proof with Kernel & Range

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Given that $L$ is a linear map such that $L:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$, and $\ker(L) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $\operatorname{range}(L) = \Bbb R^m$, show that $m = n$.

So far, I've tried to use the definitions of Kernel, and Range, but nothing is coming to mind. Any idea where I should start? By the way, I haven't learned about 'Dimension' yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you know about the rank and the nullity of $L$?

Comment: Without "dimension", this is going to be tougher. Do you know about linear independence?

Comment: Yes I know about linear independence

Answer (score 3):

$$\operatorname{dim}(\Bbb R^n) = \operatorname{dim}(\ker(L)) + \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Im}(L)) $$

Hence

$n = 0 + m$

Comment: This is very famous theorem in linear algebra.

Comment: you can also easily prove this theorem by considering the basis of the Im and the kernel and playing around.

Comment: You should write $\;\ker L\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,L\;$ , not just ker and Im . +1

Comment: I do think you need to know about dimension (notably it being well defined) before you can even start to prove this theorem. Which means this is not usable by OP yet. (But then answering the question with the given restrictions is somewhat hard.)